# Python Store Dynamically Created Entry boxes in sqlite

Tags: python, dynamic, tkinter, sqlite, sql-update

I have this code which is used to store information about a users account. Each account has its own record in a database. There is a field in each record which stores the variable `Exercises`. As each user performs multiple exercises this needs to be a list of different values. To do this is I have created a button which when clicked creates another entry box to input the exercise into. However as this list of entry are all under the same name I am having trouble storing the data held in every box. This is the code

```
    global MemberID
    intMemberID = MemberID
    self.ent_MemberID = Entry(self.FrameExercise, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"),  width = 20, text = MemberID)
    self.ent_MemberID.grid(row = 11, column = 12)
    self.ent_MemberID.insert(END, intMemberID) #no "\n"

    global ExerciseCount
    ExerciseCount = 0

    global WeightCount
    WeightCount = 0

    connection = sqlite3.connect(r"F:\Program\Accounts.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Exercises WHERE MemberID=?", (MemberID,))#comma

def new(self):
    global ExerciseCount
    ExerciseCount = ExerciseCount + 1
    print (ExerciseCount)
    for num in range(ExerciseCount):
        self.Exercises = Entry(self.FrameExercise, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"),  width = 20)
        self.Exercises.grid(row=2+ExerciseCount, column=1)

    global WeightCount
    WeightCount = WeightCount + 1
    print (WeightCount)
    for num in range(WeightCount):
        self.Weights = Entry(self.FrameExercise, bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial","16"),  width = 4)
        self.Weights.grid(row=2+WeightCount, column=2)

def Update(self):

    connection = sqlite3.connect(r"F:\Program\Accounts.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    Exercise = self.Exercises.get()
    Weight = self.Weights.get()
    global MemberID

    List = [Exercise, Weight, MemberID]

    cursor.executemany("UPDATE Exercises SET Exercise=?, Weight=? WHERE MemberID=?",(Exercise, Weight, MemberID))

    connection.commit()
```

When I create 2 entry boxes this is the error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Right now it looks like you're trying your best to _not_ resolve your issue. How can we potentially _guess_ what `MemberID` supposed to be?

Comment: MemberID is a number assigned to each account.

Answer (score 0):

`exercise`s should be stored in a separate `exercise` table that is tied to the `member` with a foreign key relationship on `MemberID`.  Then write as many `exercise`s as you want tied to the same `member`